# using(), access data from parent callee for logging purposes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, design-patterns

I have a custom build log framework that logs to a database.

For example it can do

```
L.e("Error invalid password", userGuid);
```

This works fine for general use but the application is quite complex and there are a lot of different parts that are called from the main code. For example a login sequence could send an SMS for OTP which is handled by a completely other part of the system and it does not make sense to pass a lot of values thru just for logging purposes.

What I want to achieve is to tag the log with for example userGuid so that I can search for everything related to this specific user. I also want to tag any logging in the SMS module even though the SMS module does not know anything about the user concept.

So what I am thinking of is if it is possible to get the current threadid and store some things regarding the logging in a higher level. I wonder if this is at all possible.

Psuedo code:

```
void Login(UserName, Password) {
    User user = UserManager.GetUser(UserName)
    using(L.SetUser(user.ID)) {   //Here I want to use user.ID later in code that dont know the context
        SmsManager.SendOtp(user.Phonenumber)
    }
}

public class SmsManager {
    public static void SendOtp(string phonenumber) {
        if (phonenumber == "") {
            L.error("Phone number is empty");   //How can I use the value from L.SetUser above? Could I use a hash table of threadids in L or would that be a bad idea? 
        }
    }
}
```

Kind regards
Jens

Comment: What is `L`? What does `SetUser` do? Can you have it set some property that can be read later?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us some snippets from `L`? Is that a `static` class? Does `SetUser` set a `static` variable? You could use the `using` block the way you suggest. You'd want to implement `IDisposable` and clear the `UserID` value in the `Dispose` method. But if `UserID` is a `static` variable, then this solution will not work in a multi-threaded environment (without some other changes). And the design just seems odd to me.

Overall seems like you are using `static` a lot. That can get you into trouble.

There are lots of possible solutions. Tough to say what's best without seeing some more code. Here is one way using dependency injection to keep your modules separate, as you want.

Define an interface for your logger.

```cs
public interface ILogger
{
    void Error(string message);
}
```

Implement with a class that adds the user information:

```cs
public class MessageWithUserLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _userId;

    public MessageWithUserLogger(string userId)
    {
        _userId = userId;
    }

    public void Error(string message)
    {
        L.error(message, _userId);
    }
}
```

Change `SmsManager` class to be non-`static` and depend on the `ILogger` abstraction rather than the `L` implementation:

```cs
public class SmsManager
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SmsManager(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void SendOtp(string phonenumber)
    {
        if (phonenumber == "")
        {
            _logger.Error("Phone number is empty"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Inject the logger with userID when that information is available:

```cs
void Login(UserName, Password)
{
    User user = UserManager.GetUser(UserName);
    ILogger logger = new MessageWithUserLogger(user.ID);
    SmsManager smsManager = new SmsManager(logger);
    smsManager.SendOtp(user.Phonenumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The using statement is not intended to be used like this. The using statement was introduced to be able to define a limited scope, and at the same time make sure objects are disposed using the IDisposable interface (see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

The way you are using the using statement makes it seems as if the property is sent when you start the scope, and would somehow be "unset" afterwards, but this is not the case.

When working with loggers and starting from your pseudo code, I would say your logging framework should be extended to create a context specific logger when you go into the using, and then pass the logging context to the static function. it would look then as below:

```
void Login(UserName, Password) {
    User user = UserManager.GetUser(UserName)
    using(var logContext = L.CreateContext(user.ID)) {   //Here I want to use user.ID later in code that dont know the context
        SmsManager.SendOtp(logContext, user.Phonenumber)
    }
}

public class SmsManager {
    public static void SendOtp(LogContext logContext, string phonenumber) {
        if (phonenumber == "") {
            logContext.error("Phone number is empty");   //How can I use the value from L.SetUser above? Could I use a hash table of threadids in L or would that be a bad idea? 
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of passing the log context, it is theoretically possible to store the context inside the L object and map it to a thread ID, and, later on in the functions check if there is a specific log context for that thread when you log something. In the IDisposable interface implementation of the LogContext object, you should then remove the context (which corresponds with the end of your using() scope). I would however not do this, because it "hides"  a bunch of logic, but even more, it relies on the fact that every function will be executed in the same thread. This in combination with hiding this, makes it a possible source of errors (if the user of the code isn't aware that this is linked to the thread, and changes the thread, you might miss information, make wrong assumptions based on the logging, etc). I think it is not bad practice if you have functions like the SMS manager that has a number of helper functions, to pass in a context specific object.

Also, be aware that this is a concept that exists in most popular logging libraries such as Serilog, and, in almost all cases, writing your own logging libraries isn't the most profitable business (since most of these libraries also have extensions that allow you to write a custom sink, which for example would then write the log output to a database for your specific scenario (but you get all the rest for free).